# Obtaining a copy of R. W. O'Brien's PhD thesis

Tags: specific-reference, conductors

I have read lots of papers about high-contrast material, but lots of them cite the PhD thesis by R. W. O'Brien ([see, for example Reference 2 here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0893-9659(94)90094-9)), but I couldn't find this dissertation. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not contain any physics content

Comment: @JeffDror: [The tag wikis for *specific-reference*](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-reference/info) seems to indicate that this *is* on-topic.

Comment: Ask your librarian.

Answer (score 2):

I did my PhD at Cambridge at around that time, and I recall having to provide a copy of the thesis for the University Library. If you contact the library I would guess a mechanism exists for providing copies of theses, though presumably they will charge for the service.

**Later:**

See this page [How do I access a dissertation from the University of Cambridge?](https://answers.libraries.cam.ac.uk/faq/121575) from the library web site.

> The University Library holds all Cambridge dissertations from 1921 onwards and they can be ordered from the Manuscript Reading Room (01223 333143, mss@lib.cam.ac.uk). They can't be borrowed or supplied for inter-library loan.
>
> Information on finding theses and dissertations can be found on the Theses Libguide.   Details of all Cambridge theses approved since 1970 can be found using iDiscover. They are also listed in the EThOS database.
>
> Copying of Cambridge dissertations is subject to regulations made by the Board of Graduate Studies. Personal applications for the purchase of copies of dissertations for private research can be directed to the Digital Content Unit (http://www.lib.cam.ac.uk/collections/departments/digital-content-unit ; email photo@lib.cam.ac.uk). There is a charge for this. To purchase dissertations on behalf of an institution (e.g. for library stock) the author's permission is required before a copy can be supplied.

Comment: You weren't a physics PhD at Cambridge were you? You might ken [Prof. Jo Etheridge](http://eng.monash.edu.au/about/people/profile/jether), whoI think may have been your contemporary if so.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: no, I was a physical chemist (solid state photochemistry) based in the Chem dept in Lensfield Road. Also my PhD was '83 - '86 so actually a bit later than the date in the question. I take my hat off to the physicists though, it's a long cold ride to the (new) Cavendish lab in the depths of the Cambridgeshire winter!